# htaccess redirect only if path begins with xxx

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have got the following line in my htaccess file to redirect users from /xxx to /yyy. It was created using an htaccess file generator.

```
RedirectMatch 301 /xxx(.*) yyy/$1
```

However, I have a css file in a directory like this:

```
/css/xxx1/styles.css
```

The line in the htaccess is breaking the css. Any idea what I need to do to redirect only paths that begin with xxx and not that contain xxx anywhere.

Comment: Since RedirectMatch uses regular expressions, simply add a leading circumflex …?

Comment: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/xxx(.*) yyy/$1` should work.